# what are some classic data sets, and they stories behind them that made them famous?

Tags: dataset, history

I'm familiar with some famous datasets and the stories behind them, but I'd love to know more.

for instance:

1. The [*Iris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) dataset - a botanician said that it is possible to differentiate between species of Iris flowers by the measurements of the petals, and then Fisher, a statistician, described a linear discriminant model for making these classifications
2. The *Titanic* dataset - describing who survived and who didnt in the titanic disaster.

There are [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set#Classic_data_sets), of course.

so:

- What famous data sets are you aware of?
- What was the background story?
- What made them famous?
- As a teaching tool, what are they commonly used for showing?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/tiny-real-datasets-for-giving-examples-in-class, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/what-are-good-datasets-to-illustrate-particular-aspects-of-statistical-analysis,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16130/datasets-for-data-visualization-examples-teaching-and-research