Nice real datasets for visually illustrating concepts
I am looking for relatively small (< 1000 sample) real datasets for use in teaching.
I would like

regression examples with a non-linear relationship between a single input and output
classification examples with two features and non-linear decision
boundaries

I am looking for these to visually illustrate various regression and classification techniques.

Some possible duplicates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/tiny-real-datasets-for-giving-examples-in-class, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169450/what-are-some-good-datasets-to-learn-basic-machine-learning-algorithms-and-why, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16130/datasets-for-data-visualization-examples-teaching-and-research, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/what-are-good-datasets-to-illustrate-particular-aspects-of-statistical-analysis,

@kjetilbhalvorsen while useful, these previous questions do not specifically address the visualizable component of my question.  I restrict to 1 and 2 dimensional features for regression and classification, respectively, for ease of visualization.  I am also seeking non-linear relationships and non-linear decision boundaries.

My hope was that these desiderata would be common enough that others had done the work of sifting through the millions of datasets out there.  It seems useful to have a dedicated question collecting these.

While not real, Anscombe's Quartet is one of the best datasets for illustrating pitfalls in nonlinearity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet

How broad or complex is your notion of nonlinearity? For example, many neural net basis functions capture S-shaped nonlinearity with some ML enthusiasts even claiming that they capture all nonlinearities. S-shaped growth functions are both ancient and ubiquitous...eg, Seneca's Law or the growth rate of pea pods, not to mention that human growth rates over the life cycle are markedly nonlinear.

The gamair package contains many datasets used explicitly for modeling generalized additive models (GAMs) and would make for good examples for nonlinear regression techniques. Since you also asked about classification, the wesdr dataset includes data which predicts the presence of retinopathy, which can be modeled as a function of duration of diabetes (but also contains other variables), containing around 600 observations:
#### Libraries and Data ####
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)
data("wesdr")
head(wesdr)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- gam(
  ret ~ s(dur),
  data = wesdr,
  family = binomial()
)

#### Plot Fitted Model ###
plot(fit,
     xlab = "Duration",
     ylab = "s(Duration)",
     main = "Predicted Retinopathy by Duration",
     trans = plogis)



Here is a an example of nonlinear regression. (It has heteroscedasticity as an added bonus!).
This Motorcycle dataset is popular in the computer experiments community as an illustrative example. It gives the acceleration measured by sensors in a motorcycle helmet during a simulated crash.

It is available from many places by searching "motorcycle acceleration dataset", such as here.
It seems to originate from:
Silverman, Bernhard W. "Some aspects of the spline smoothing approach to non‐parametric regression curve fitting." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological) 47.1 (1985): 1-21.
